# Pandas: numpy.where logic with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

New to Python Data Science

The below is my Raw_data

```
raw_data = {'var1': ['true','false','ture'],'var2': [10,20,50], 'var3':['eggs','milk','eggs']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['var1','var2','var3'])`
```

Expermented code but not working

```
def my_fun (var1,var2,var3,var4):
    df[var4]= np.where((df[var1] == 'true', 
                       df[var3] == 'eggs',
                       df[var2] < 10),
                       'hello',
                       'zello')
return df
```

Here I like to use var1, var2 and var3 conditions and get the conditional result. Please help

Comment: "_but not working_" - please include the complete error message. Also, you probably should use `True` and `False` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`.

Comment: Not to mention `True` instead of `"ture"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use Boolean `True` / `False` rather than strings to simplify your logic. To apply this conversion to series `'var1'`:

```
df['var1'] = df['var1'] == 'true'
```

You can then use the bitwise operator `&` to compare Boolean series:

```
def my_fun (var1,var2,var3,var4):
    df[var4]= np.where(df[var1] & df[var3].eq('eggs') & df[var2].lt(10),
                       'hello', 'zello')
    return df
```

A less efficient alternative is to use `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
def my_fun (var1,var2,var3,var4):
    conds = (df[var1], df[var3] == 'eggs', df[var2] < 10)
    df[var4]= np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(conds), 'hello', 'zello')
    return df
```

Comment: You could also use `numpy.all` with an `axis` argument, or just `&` twice.

Comment: @jpp For a tiny amount of data like this there's probably no difference, but if you had any significant amount, `np.logical_and` would waste some significant time dealing with the Series objects during reduction, (presumably because it isn't optimized for this like Pandas bitwise-ands are). You could avoid this of course using `.values` everywhere but that gets pretty verbose.

Comment: @jpp Works great. Can add additional condition to np.where? (df[var1].values == 'true') & 
                       (df[var3].values == 'eggs') &
                       (df[var2]].values == 10), 'equal'

Comment: @jpp I am accepting your answer. However, I am able to add new condition by adding addtional np.where. Thank you so much.